# Error: ID strings of the products were saved as an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m trying to store each of the product’s id in the cartItems, however, the ID is being saved as an array as demonstrated in the picture below. Instead of being saved like this `id: "aRLMZkiSU7T0lcsPCSsV"`

How do I fix this?

[image]

code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/add-to-cart-jsd9fd?file=/src/App.js:0-2587

Below are the codes:

```
export default function App() {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

  const handleAdd = (id, name, size, cat, color) => {
    console.log("add", id, name, size, cat, color);
    const productExist = cartItems.find((item) => item.id === id);

    if (productExist) {
      setCartItems(
        cartItems.map((item) =>
          item.id === id
            ? { ...productExist, quantity: productExist.quantity + 1 }
            : item
        )
      );
    } else {
      setCartItems([
        ...cartItems,
        { ...id, name, size, cat, color, quantity: 1 }
      ]);
    }
  };

  // const handleAdd = (item) => {
  //   console.log("add", item);
  // };

  console.log(cartItems);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {products.map((index) => (
        <ul key={index.id}>
          <li>
            <b>{index.prodName}</b>
          </li>
          <li>Category: {index.cat}</li>
          <li>Size: {index.size}</li>
          {Object.entries(index.colorMap).map((color) => (
            <>
              {color[1] !== 0 ? (
                <>
                  {color[0]}
                  <button
                    onClick={(e) =>
                      handleAdd(
                        index.id,
                        index.prodName,
                        index.size,
                        index.cat,
                        color[0]
                      )
                    }
                  >
                    Add to Cart
                  </button>
                  {/* <button onClick={(e) => handleAdd(index)}>Add to Cart</button> */}
                </>
              ) : (
                <>2</>
              )}
              <br />
            </>
          ))}
          Php {index.price}.00
        </ul>
      ))}
      {/* <Cart cartItems={cartItems} /> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you try removing spread operator, ```...``` in this line ```{ ...id, name, size, cat, color, quantity: 1 }```  Forked Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/add-to-cart-forked-8bi8yc

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Thank you, removing the spread operator does work

Comment: Good. Welcome !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the spread operator from Id.

```
 else {
  setCartItems([
    ...cartItems,
    { id, name, size, cat, color, quantity: 1 }
  ]);
}
```